Java array memory size
For those eager to flag this as duplicate, this question is not related to any of the questions like:
How to calculate Java array's memory size?
Memory size of Java 32-bit system int[] arrays

In Java when an array of primitive int is created:
int[] arr = new int[1000];

Does the JVM allocate memory for the entire array length * 4 bytes, i.e. 4000 bytes after the above statement? Let's not bother about constant overheads like headers etc.
My understanding is that in case of primitive numeric types, e.g. int, double etc., the default value '0' is also a valid value, hence needs memory. In effect, full required memory must be allocated at the time of such declarations.
How could I verify it?

Don't just state that it isn't duplicative, explain why. (Note that sparse allocations exist -- some operating systems allow virtual memory to be allocated without any physical memory backing it until contents are actually added; so it's very possible that this is undefined behavior and JVMs that today actually allocate physical memory pages could stop doing so without notice in future versions, making this a question that there doesn't exist an enforced-by-specification answer to at all)

@CharlesDuffy because here I'm trying to discriminate between memory for default values at this time of declaration vs when 'actual' values which might be filled later. The behaviour of primitive array should be different than reference type. This aspect is not addressed in other mentioned questions.

An int value of 0 is still a 32-bit value.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk Yes, that was my guess as well. However, any definite way to verify that it's inconsequential to set any value later?

Plenty of ways to practically measure behavior with a specific JVM. You could use procfs to read the map of where virtual memory is mapped by, both before allocation and then after explicit use, f/e

@PresisentJamesKPolk, yes, but you only need one page full of zeros, and if someone allocates 5gb of zeros then you can map all that virtual memory to read only copies of that single page and only replace them with writable content when you get a page fault caused by someone trying to write. Linux can do this automatically if you use the right malloc and madvise flags, and I'm sure other operating systems can too.

This, how calculate java array memory usage may contain the information that you want. Also, check out Array of objects in Memory

In terms of measuring practical behavior, (again, with the understanding that it should be understood to be applicable to only a specific JVM/OS pair), I'd also look at the tools in the valgrind suite.

Maybe VisualVM can help?

In particular, to see if the technique i referenced is in use, watch the page fault counter for your process the first time you write to the previously-empty array. If it doesn't increment that's firm proof. (Do make sure you allocated enough memory for any of these techniques to apply, but not so much as to force content to be paged out).

@CharlesDuffy You understand that new int[] doesn't allocate memory using syscalls? It allocate it in heap. Yes it can lead to increase of heap, but it will be quite hard to track what memory in heap is actually initialized, so I doubt JVM does it.

Your argument for the primitive types is the same for the array. It will be allocated and filled with the 0 value.

Chapter 10 Arrays the value of the component type is well defined, so yes it will allocate everything at once. 10.3 also confirms that. "An array initializer creates an array and provides initial values for all its components."

@matt
"An array initializer creates an array and provides initial values for all its components." -- null initial values for reference type arrays and 0 initial values for primitive numerical arrays have different memory ramifications.

I don't get you. The Object reference type has a fixed size, even if it is null. So an Object[] is going to be a different size than a byte[] of the same length yes, but the value is calculatable. Also, you can test by setting the max heap -Xmx50m and try allocating an array that takes up more space than that. You'll get an OMM.

Post your additional details as edits to your Question, not Comments.

@talex, re the comment above ("does not allocate memory using syscalls"), I'm hard-placed to know where to start. There's only one syscall generally used to ask the OS for memory, and that's sbrk() -- your usual malloc(), free() etc don't make any syscall to the OS as long as there's enough memory space already available, but just track the subset of what's used on the heap. So that tracking you describe as unreasonable is already done in any language that even has a malloc implementation.

@CharlesDuffy I doubt that malloc() is involved in process of allocation of the memory by JVM for new object. Don't know why you mentioned it.

@talex, the JVM has its own (much more advanced) alternative, but that's my point: memory allocators are done in 90% in userspace, and even C has one (which is why I pointed out malloc), so the claim that tracking which content is used or free within the heap is too complex is absurd.

Why are you telling me that? I never said tracking can't be done, all information is available. I just said it will be impractical in situation when most objects are smaller than memory page, So such tracking will be beneficial in super rare edge cases.

Let’s see
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
            if(test(i) != i + 0x123)
                throw new AssertionError();
        }
    }
  
    static int test(int someArg) {
        int[] arr = new int[1000];
        arr[42] = someArg;
        return arr[42] + 0x123;
    }
}

jdk-17\bin\javac -d %tmp% src\Test.java
jdk-17\bin\java -XX:CompileCommand=print,Test.test -cp %tmp% Test

…
============================= C2-compiled nmethod ==============================
----------------------------------- Assembly -----------------------------------

…

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[Verified Entry Point]
  # {method} {0x0000020061400350} 'test' '(I)I' in 'Test'
  # parm0:    rdx       = int
  #           [sp+0x20]  (sp of caller)
  0x000002004e6e2f00:   sub    $0x18,%rsp
  0x000002004e6e2f07:   mov    %rbp,0x10(%rsp)
  0x000002004e6e2f0c:   mov    %edx,%eax
  0x000002004e6e2f0e:   add    $0x123,%eax
  0x000002004e6e2f14:   add    $0x10,%rsp
  0x000002004e6e2f18:   pop    %rbp
  0x000002004e6e2f19:   cmp    0x340(%r15),%rsp             ;   {poll_return}
  0x000002004e6e2f20:   ja     0x000002004e6e2f27
  0x000002004e6e2f26:   ret
  0x000002004e6e2f27:   movabs $0x2004e6e2f19,%r10          ;   {internal_word}
  0x000002004e6e2f31:   mov    %r10,0x358(%r15)
  0x000002004e6e2f38:   jmp    0x0000020046c63400           ;   {runtime_call SafepointBlob}
  0x000002004e6e2f3d:   hlt
  0x000002004e6e2f3e:   hlt
  0x000002004e6e2f3f:   hlt
[Exception Handler]
  0x000002004e6e2f40:   jmp    0x0000020046d05480           ;   {no_reloc}
[Deopt Handler Code]
  0x000002004e6e2f45:   call   0x000002004e6e2f4a
  0x000002004e6e2f4a:   subq   $0x5,(%rsp)
  0x000002004e6e2f4f:   jmp    0x0000020046c626a0           ;   {runtime_call DeoptimizationBlob}
  0x000002004e6e2f54:   hlt
  0x000002004e6e2f55:   hlt
  0x000002004e6e2f56:   hlt
  0x000002004e6e2f57:   hlt
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

As we can see, aside from the instructions dealing with the method invocation itself (i.e. stack manipulation), the C2 generated code for the test method consists of the two instructions, mov    %edx,%eax and add    $0x123,%eax. No array allocation, no array zeroing.
This is, of course, the most extreme scenario. But it demonstrates, that there is no requirement to do what has been written literally, as long as the resulting behavior is compatible.

Besides that, the term “allocation” is ambiguous. It implies changing some data structure to record that a particular region of memory is not available for other purposes. But there are differences in who shares this structure and hence, the same point of view regarding what is allocated.
Small allocations are usually done in a TLAB which is dedicated to a single thread. So allocating a small array in a TLAB only makes a difference to that thread. From the other threads’ point of view, the memory of that TLAB wasn’t available anyway. But even when a new TLAB is allocated from the heap memory shared by all threads, it’s memory that is considered already reserved to the JVM process from the operating system’s point of view. Only when the JVM expands or shrinks the entire heap memory, it will affect what the operating system reserves to the JVM (which is what may have an impact on other processes).
But even when memory is allocated from the operating system, it doesn’t have to be backed by physical memory. The operating system may postpone this operation to the point where the first actual write operation happens. Up to that point, the memory may still be considered all-zero-filled, which is the typical default, and the system does not need actual memory for an all-zero-filled region.

Yes, the JVM does allocate all memory at once.

Virtual memory only, or physical memory as well? Is this defined by specification or implementation?

@CharlesDuffy The host Operating System (OS) manages virtual memory, not the Java Virtual Machine (JVM). Like any other app (process), the JVM always believes in the illusion that it operates upon physical memory (RAM).

@CharlesDuffy I doubt specification says anything about physical memory. It may run on fairy dust and good wishes as far as specification concerns. And since JVM most probably initialize memory at allocation it will be allocated by OS as well.

@talex, ..."most probably" is something I'm not sure about. It's the easy implementation, sure, but for something like a JVM where there's serious engineering investment into making it fast, it makes sense to recognize corner cases where you can tell the OS to map the whole virtual span to a single zeroed-out page in read-only mode and only allocate real memory when there's an attempt to write to something in that span triggering a page fault.

@talex, ...indeed, see the answer by Holger definitively proving that at least one JVM does not do the easy and obvious thing.

@CharlesDuffy Holger demonstrated that optimizer use escape analysis to find object that never escape method and doesn't allocate those objects.

@CharlesDuffy In Chapter 10. Arrays of the Java specs, I do not see any mention of memory, neither physical nor virtual, other than OutOfMemoryError. Indeed, I see no requirement that the array’s elements be contiguous in memory. Being contiguous would be an implementation detail. The spec merely says: “Space is allocated for a new array of that length.”

@BasilBourque, there's a lot of room to tune kernel behavior from userspace -- yes, the kernel is doing the work, but madvise &c (where "&c" extends to tricks like mmap'ing unlinked sparse files) lets applications instruct the kernel about how to do that work. And mmap of an unlinked sparse file on shmfs is absolutely an example of allocating virtual memory without immediately backing it with physical memory.

@CharlesDuffy the HotSpot JVM by default allocates memory for the heap in a way that it is not backed by physical memory until the first actual write occurs. That’s why the -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch option exist, which forces accesses to the memory pages so they are eagerly assigned to physical memory. Usually, filling an array with its default values (zeros) on allocation does work like an access that will make the page backed by physical memory, but as discussed in this article, this initial filling can be eliminated in some cases…


Does the JVM allocate memory for the entire array length * 4 bytes, i.e. 4000 bytes after the above statement

Java will do it as you say, and one more thing is that the memory needs to be contiguous. Because the data of arrar is consecutive, it is necessary to fully allocate it when initializing the array, if there is no contiguous memory, out of mem will occur.
Some space will be needed for the array itself, but it's only about 4 to 8 bytes.
For example: I will allocate parking spaces for A to accommodate 100 cars. And allocate parking spaces for B to accommodate 50 cars right behind A.
Even though A may not have all 100 cars yet, I need to know the exact size of each car to accurately calculate the space needed for 100 cars to provide parking for A. The same applies to B for next behind A.

This completely disregards the distinction between virtual and physical memory. Virtual memory for an array needs to be contiguous, but on any 64-bit platform there's an enormous amount of it available; and that virtual memory absolutely does not need to be mapped contiguously into physical memory -- each page of virtual memory can be allocated to a completely different place in physical memory, or not mapped to any physical memory at all (f/e, if swapped out, or backed by mmap'd disk).
